# Azure AD On-Behalf-Of with oAuth & SAML

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, nextcloud

We're using the [Azure AD On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of) for connecting a user to several services through a single API gateway. Now we'd like to add another service (Nextcloud, synced through LDAP) which only supports SAML 2.0 and no oAuth2.

Is it possible to somehow convert an oAuth-Token into a SAML-Token, maybe through an Azure AD API? Or is there some other way to connect this service I maybe haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible currently. Also the authentication libraries (ADAL/MSAL) do not support SAML tokens