# Convert Jwt token or claims principal to SAML token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, saml-2.0

Using Azure AD, I have a .NET Core Web API Controller that has authenticated the user using OAuth2 and I have a JWT Bearer token and a Claims Principal.

Is there any way of using either of these to generate a SAML token so I can call another API, that only supports SAML, on behalf of this user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK , currently that is not possible in a on-behalf-of scenario . Similar discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47908768/azure-ad-on-behalf-of-with-oauth-saml) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ef39260f-cdf0-40d8-bbb1-267c538534c2/how-to-generate-a-saml-or-saml2-token-base-on-jwt?forum=WindowsAzureAD) are for your reference .

Comment: Given this, am I right to think that the only solution is for the user to authenticate twice, so as to acquire each token?

Comment: In your scenario , i'm afraid yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible and supported scenario by Azure AD v.1 endpoint.

This is supported as non-standard extension of the On-Behalf-Of authorization flow in OAuth2 framework. More details on the concrete implementation by Azure AD v.1 endpoint is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#saml-assertions-obtained-with-an-oauth20-obo-flow).

Of course, your OIDC application must be granted at least "user_impersonation" permission on the SAML integrated app/api in order the On-Behalf-Of flow to work.

This has been supported since almost the beginning in v.1 endpoints.